# Is there a GUI for Embedded MongoDB (Flapdoodle)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, spring-test

I'm working on a POC using spring boot application with mongodb, and embedded mongodb (flapdoodle) for unit tests.

I've searched for a GUI for embedded mongodb (flapdoodle), but haven't found anything about this. Is there a GUI for embedded mongodb ?

Comment: In case of using spring-data, you can easily switch on spring-rest and start using UI browser for repository resources [See documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_hal_browser)

Answer (score 3):

Just use any mongodb GUI tool. Start the spring boot so the mongodb instance is alive and then use the GUI tool. I was able to use [Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) to connect to my embedded instance at `localhost:37681`. The port of course depends on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot logs the MongoDB port when it starts the unit test execution, I am using the URI property to connect the embedded DB and it is mongodb://localhost/test, in this case the port would change for each run. Also if you have multiple unit test classes configured with Test profile then MongoDB will be created for each class, meaning if you are inserting records from one unit test class and trying to retrieve from other unit test class would fail as the second one uses a new connection. Below is a sample logs with MongoDB port,

> [INFO]    - - 2020-09-02 17:47:06.782 740 --- [localhost:51767]
> org.mongodb.driver.connection            : -- Opened connection
> [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:1}] to localhost:**51767**